# Is this a good enough proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Is this proof good enough? If not, any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Either exhibit $333 $ diﬀerent boolean functions on the three variables $p; q; r,$
or prove that there aren’t $333$ diﬀerent such functions.

**Proof**: Using the formula $2^{2^n}$ for calculating the total number of functions any boolean function can have, the total number of functions the variables $p,q,r$ have is 256.Therefore there aren't $333 $ different boolean function in the variable $p,q,r.$

Comment: Looks fine, **if** the result about the number of Boolean functions has already been proved. If not, a proof would be needed, at least for $n=3$.

Comment: You might want to say what $n$ is in the formula.

Comment: if we let $n=3$ then we would have $2^8$ and that's 256. Therefore we don't have $333$ different boolean functions for $p,q,$ and $r$

Comment: Yes it has been proven. I shall explain what  "n" is then. Thanks so much for the help. :)

Comment: I'm also studying proof writing. It gets frustrating with relations D:

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments:

1. You may want to explain what $n$ is in your proof
2. Otherwise, your proof is fine--assuming that the formula $2^{2^n}$ has already been proven elsewhere.

*Converting comments to answer to get off "unanswered" queue*